# Can we generalize the existence of a orthogonal representation of a compact Lie group $G$?

Tags: vector-spaces, representation-theory, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds, inner-products

Namely if $V$ is a $\mathbb{R}$-linear vector space, with Euclidean inner product $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$, and $\rho:G\rightarrow GL(V)$ is a representation of a compact Lie group $G$ on $V$, then there exists a new scalar product such that $\rho$ is an orthogonal representation.

The new scalar product, which we will call $\eta$ is defined by:
$$\eta(v,w)=\int_G\langle \rho(g)v,\rho(g)w\rangle \sigma$$
where $\sigma$ is a nowhere vanishing, right invariant top form on $G$. To me, the key part of the proof that I'm interested is showing that $\eta(v,v)$ is an inner product, which follows from the fact that $\langle \rho(g)v,\rho(g)w\rangle$ is positive definite, and from well known statement about integration of top forms on smooth manifolds.

I am curious if we can relax the conditions on $\langle \cdot, \cdot\rangle$, to be only symmetric, bilinear, and nondegenerate. Does defining the new scalar product in the same way yield a `pseudo orthogonal' representation of $G$ on $V$? Would the new scalar product have the same signature as $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$? If the process prescribed above doesn't work in this, then is there anyway to alter it so that it does?

Comment: Yes, it will be again symmetric and bilinear, which is an easy exercise you should try to do once you understood the proof that works for inner product. But, in general, you might get zero form even if the original form was nondegenerate.

Comment: Symmetric and bilinear are clear to me. How do we see we don't necessarily get a non degenerate form? Is there a way to modify it, perhaps by developing  a notion of integrating continuous forms, and then taking the absolute value of the $\langle gv,gw\rangle$, and then by applying a minus sign or plus sign, after integration, depending on the sign of $\langle v, w\rangle $ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the following example: $G={\mathbb Z}_2$ (the group of 2 elements), $V={\mathbb R}^2$ equipped with the bilinear form $B$ whose quadratic form is $x^2-y^2$. Suppose that $G$ acts on $V$ so that its generator swaps the coordinate lines. I will leave you to check that the bilinear form $B'$ obtained from $B$ by averaging over $G$ is identically zero.

Comment: Could we change the definition of $\eta$ so that we obtain a nondegenerate form?

Comment: @Chris: I do not see how, but if you give me a formula I will take a look.

Comment: @Chris: Actually, one can show that such a definition does not exist. The reason is that orthogonal groups $O(n)$ do not embed in maximal compact subgroups of the groups $O(p, n-p)$, whenever $p\ne 0, p\ne n$.

Comment: I see makes sense, thank you for the insight